# Watchkit Maps: show current location

Tags: ios, location, watchkit

I have made application where we can calculate current location in extention app and I would like to show it at watch. How to do this? There is a methods only to show pin with different color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the coordinates for the location you can use `- (void)addAnnotation (CLLocationCoordinate2D)location withImage:(UIImage *)image centerOffset:(CGPoint)offset` on WKInterfaceMap.  Pass in the location for the first parameter and pass in a UIImage for the pin that you want to show for the current location.  You will also want to be sure and call `setVisibleMapRect` so that the map shows the location.