# How to add Custom Map Pins to the Map View on the Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-watch

I am beginning to code for the Apple Watch and I am wondering how can I do this:

Thank you!

[image: Screenshot from Apple Interface Guidelines]

Comment: have you tried this? 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/27426950/1336105

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to add a map view to your controller (for example `InterceController.swift`)

Then, you can call these lines in your `InterfaceController.swift`'s `awakeWithContext()` or `willActivate()`

```
 let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: 51.530777,
            longitude: -0.139364
        )

 let span = MKCoordinateSpan(
            latitudeDelta: 0.005,
            longitudeDelta: 0.005
       )

 let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

 map.setRegion(region)

 map.addAnnotation(location, withImageNamed: "bee.png", centerOffset: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
```

The key is to call `addAnnotation(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, withImageNamed name: String!, centerOffset offset: CGPoint)`

Equivalent Objective-C code:

```
  CLLocationCoordinate2D location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.530777, -0.139364);

    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.005, 0.005);

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span);

    [self.map setRegion:region];

    [self.map addAnnotation:location withImageNamed:@"bee.png" centerOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```

Comment: Is it possible to add location or custom text also along with annotation, like we have for iPhone.